# How to include the ID and the variables in react-apollo-hook's useMutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-hooks

I have my schema set up like the following:

```
updatePost(id: ID!, data: UpdatePostInput!): Post!
```

I also have my front end query set up as following:

```
export const UPDATE_POST_MUTATION = gql`
 mutation UpdatePost($id: ID!, $title: String, $body: String, $location: String, $published: Boolean) {
    updatePost(
        id: $id,
        data: {
            title: $title, body: $body, location: $location, published: $published
        }
    ){
      id
      title
      body
    }
  }
`
```

If I wanted to use `useMutation` in this situation, how would I include the ID and the variables? 
I tried the following, but didn't work:

```
const formSubmit = useMutation(UPDATE_POST_MUTATION, {
        variables: { id: props.match.params.id, variables } // or ...variables  
    })
```

Comment: there's so such "variables" key in your mutation. probably you mean `data`.

Comment: @codekaizer how would I include it?